# A conjecture about irreducible polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Let $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$, define $\operatorname{P}^+(f)$ as the number of primes $>0$ that $f$ assumes at distinct integral arguments.

**Theorem**: If $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is non constant and reducible of degree $n$, then $\operatorname{P}^+(f)\leq n$. And for all $n$ there are non constant reducible polynomials of degree n such that $\operatorname{P}^+(f)=n$.
[Acta Arith.,104.2 (2002) 117-127.]

Most polynomials are irreducible but using the theorem for an irreducibility test would be inefficient since a lot of irreducible polynomials has a fixed divisor $>1$ and wouldn't pass the test.

A conjecture related to the conjecture of Bunjakowsky states:

**Conjecture**: If $ f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is non constant and irreducible, then $f(a)/d$ assumes primes for an infinit number of distinct integral arguments $a$, where $d$ is the largest fixed divisor of $f$.

[Irreducibility of Polynomials Whose Coefficients are Integers](http://www.hri.res.in/~thanga/papers/mnl.pdf) Page 32.

This makes me wonder if the following hypothesis is true:

> $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ of degree $n>0$ with coprime coefficients is irreducible, iff $\;\operatorname{P}^+(d^{-1}\cdot f)>
> n$ or $\;\operatorname{P}^+(d^{-1}\cdot (-f))>
> n$, where $d$ is the greatest fixed divisor of $f$.

$\operatorname{P}^+$ is extended above and defined even for integer-valued polynomials with rational coefficients. Proofs or counter-examples?

---

With a test program using the hypothesis on Eisenstein polynomials $f$ with random coefficients between $-19$ and $19$ and random degree between $2$ and $5$, testing both $f$ and $-f$, resulted in no miss in $1,000,000$ polynomials. The only drawback is the risk of overflow when evaluating the polynomials for higher degrees and greater coefficients.

Comment: Bunjakowsky's conjecture starts with $d=1$ where $d = gcd(f(\mathbb{Z}))$. What do  you get with your question assuming $d=1$ ? If $f(X)= g(X)h(X)$ is reducible and $f(n) = \pm p$ then $g(n) = \pm 1$ or $h(n) = \pm 1$. Write $g(X) = 1+g_2(X)\prod_{n \in g^{-1}(1)} (X-n)$. What happens if $g(m) = -1$ ? Do you see the problem when $d \ne 1$ ?

Comment: @reuns: No! Do you mean that the hypothesis would give false irreducible polynomials?

Comment: Can you solve the case $d=1$ ? If not then this is what you should ask about. My comment aims at showing how to start with it. If $g(m) = -1$ then $g_2(m)\prod_{n \in g^{-1}(1)} (m-n) = -2$. Since $2$ is prime that doesn't leave so many choices.

Comment: @reuns: Can you elaborate on this in an answer? It would be most interesting, especially if your idea may be used to construct counter-examples, reducible polynomials that would pass as irreducible.

Comment: So ? What did you get as improving the simplest case in my answer ?

Comment: The hypothesis above is false: there are $5$ positive primes of the form $\frac{x\cdot(x^2-8x+17)}{2}$, of which $3$ are distinct. Also, there are $4$ positive primes of the form $\frac{x\cdot(x^2+17)}{6}$, all of which are distinct. Both are reducible cubics (polynomials of degree $3$).

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic: These two polynomials are not over $\mathbb Z$. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Lehs, I meant $x\cdot(x^2-8x+17)$ and $x\cdot(x^2+17)$, respectively.

Comment: @JovanRadenkovic, You are right.

Answer (score 1):

- The simplest case :

Let $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$. It is said irreducible iff $f(X) = g(X)h(X)  \implies g(X)=\pm1$ or $h(X) = \pm1$. Let $d = gcd(f(\mathbb{Z}))$. Assume $d=1$ and $| f(n)|$ is prime more than $2 \deg(f)$ times.

If $f(X) = g(X)h(X)$ is reducible, then $f(n) = \pm p$ implies 
$n$ is a root of $g(X)^2-1$ or $h(X)^2-1$. But those polynomials are of degree $2\deg(g), 2 \deg(f)-2\deg(g)$, so they have at most $2\deg(f)$ roots. A contradiction. Whence $f$ is irreducible.

- To improve the bound $2 \deg(f)$, you need to split each case : $g(n)=1,g(n)=-1,h(n)=1,h(n)=-1$ and factorize.
- Then look at the case $d=2$, you'll have more cases and some of them will probably allow more than $\deg(f)$ prime values.

Comment: You are right and I have corrected the question.